# Solr: how to delete a collection?

Tags: solr

I am using solr 4.9, not adding any additional shard, just use whatever default it comes with it.  I have created a collection and tried to delete it by using the following api :

```
http://<host>/solr/admin/collections?action=DELETE&name=collectionName
```

but it returns error :

> Solr instance is not running in SolrCloud mode

My Solr is not solrCloud, but how do I delete my collection?

Answer (score 69):

Go to the solr folder and Do this..

```
bin/solr delete -c collection_name
```

and restart solr with

```
bin/solr restart
```

Comment: For the restart command, you have to specify the port option, at least the default port, like this: `bin/solr restart -p 8983`

Comment: I did go to the solr fodler, but I all I get is 

`-bash: bin/solr: No such file or directory
`

Comment: @Suraj then you can use `. /solr delete -c collection_name`

Comment: Is restarting Solr really necessary?

Answer (score 9):

**n.b.** Tested against **Solr 4.9**, *should* work with newer versions.

```
curl -v http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=UNLOAD&deleteInstanceDir=true&core=collectionName
```

Comment: This is for cores, not collections. See Adam Seabridge' post

Answer (score 8):

You can delete the `Solr` Collection in two ways.

**1) From the command prompt:**

Launch the command prompt from where you have extracted the `Apache Solr`. Run the below Command

`Solr\bin>solr delete -c My_Collection`

**2) From the Solr Admin Console:**

`/admin/collections?action=DELETE&name=collection`

For more information about the `Apache Solr Collection API`.
[Apache Solr Collection API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html)

Answer (score 7):

According to this guide (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API) this API is working only, when you are in a SolrCloud mode.

If you want to just delete core or just delete all docs in that core, take a look here - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin

Answer (score 4):

Or do this with the API instead:

http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=DELETE&collection=collection1&shard=shard1&replica=core_node1

Answer (score 4):

You can delete a collection in three ways in the recent versions of Solr.

1. You can delete the collection manually by using the `bin/solr` tool
2. You can delete the collection manually via Solr Admin
3. You can delete the collection by using the Collections API
4. You can delete the collection by using the V2 API

Deleting a collection using the `bin/solr` tool is simple. You go to your `SOLR_HOME` directory and you run:

```
bin/solr delete -c COLLECTION_NAME
```

To delete a collection using the Collections API you would run a command like this:

```
curl 'localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=DELETE&name=COLLECTION_NAME'
```

Finally, to use the V2 API and delete a collection using it you would do the following:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:8983/api/c/COLLECTION_NAME'
```

If you plan on removing the collection very rarely, you can do that manually. If that is something commonly used - for example with aliases and time-based data I would suggest using the V2 API as this is the newest one and will probably replace the old APIs at some point.

Answer (score 2):

You could use curl

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?wt=json&action=UNLOAD&core=gettingstarted"
```

Where *gettingstarted* is the name of the core that you want to delete.
Please note that the above assumes that *solr* is running on port **8983**.

Answer (score 1):

Though Adam's response is correct, here's the documentation to help use it: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/collections-api.html#delete

I got stuck on this one for a while and was only getting the invalid deleting of cores answer, which, I'm guessing used to work for collections, but does not in newer versions.